# Proving probability density function of sigma notation

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a question that is WAY over my head, and I wanted to ask any kind of help.

Suppose $f_i(x)= 1, · · · , n$ are PDFs. That is, $f_i(x)≥0$ and $\int f_i(x)dx=1$ for all $i=1, · · · , n$. Consider a function
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i f_i(x)$$
where $p_i > 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i =1$ .

Show that $g(x)$ is also a PDF.

Comment: Use the fact that integral is a linear operator.

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb that I didn't realize that tidbit. I gotta shake off this phobia of integrals before midterms roll in O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have explicitly written what it takes for a function to be a PDF you now have to verify that $g(x)$ satisfies these conditions.

For $g(x)\geq 0$ you should simply note that each $p_if_i(x)$ is a product of a positive ($p_i$) factor and a non-negative function $f_i(x)$, so each $p_if_i(x)\geq0$ and of course so is their sum.

Now, $\int g(x)dx=\int\sum p_if_i(x)=\sum p_i\int f_i(x)=\sum p_i=1$, as required, where the order of summation and integration can be changed because the sum is finite.

Comment: Thank you! The latter part was what was really bugging me, and now I know that I was just paralyzed with PDF that I forgot how to integrate ^^;;;. Thank you so much for your help!!!